# new to php, problem with form,POST,and database

Tags: php

im learning php and to keep it simple (i think), this is what im trying to do below.

--Work so far:

I made a small mini form and what i want to do is that when the person enters their email address, that a few things happen:

1. display a dummy message with actual first name based on database info gotten from email entered.
2. delete DB row based on email entered.

the process page that comes next has a custom message like " hello NAME HERE, sorry to see you go blah blah"

Now i havent written the account deletion part because im getting an error. i don't get syntax or any other errors in DW or Aptana..just when i test.
the error that i receive is: Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_error - assumed 'mysqli_error' in line 32 which is this line that has

```
$sn_nameQueryStringResults = mysqli_query($connect2db, $sn_nameQueryString) or die( "Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);
```

this is what i have so far for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="snDelAcc_proc.php">
<table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>Enter your email address here:</td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="accDel" width="250" >
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

and this is the process page:

```
<?php




// - - connect to db.
$connect2db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','passhere','dbtest');
if(!$connect2db){
    die("Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);
}

//get emailfrom first page.
$emailaddy = $_POST['accDel'];


$sn_nameQueryString = " SELECT FROM email_list WHERE email = '$emailaddy'";




$sn_nameQueryStringResults = mysqli_query($connect2db, $sn_nameQueryString) or die( "Sorry but theres a connection to database error" . mysqli_error);




//get the name with fetch
$actualFnameGet = mysqli_fetch_array($sn_nameQueryStringResults);
//$sn_query = " DELETE FROM email_list WHERE email= ";


echo $actualFnameGet['firstname'];


?>
```

any ideas as to why im wrong? 
Im a bit lost, thanks in advance.

Comment: use `mysqli_connect_error()` instead of `mysqli_error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your error can't be printed because mysqli_error is a function, so you have to write `mysqli_error()`.

Second, you have an error in your query: Either enter all the fields you want or simply a `*`:

```
SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE email = ...
```

Last but not least, your query is very vulnerable to sql injections by putting the post variable `$emailaddy` directly into the query without escaping it, so you should use:

```
"SELECT * FROM email_list WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($emailaddy)."'";
```

Comment: thank you kindly. worked. sql injections..ive heard of it, but im not there yet lol. im a COMPLETE noob lol. but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_error` is a function, which is supposed to be `mysqli_error($link)` where `$link` is the connection.

In your case `mysqli_error($connect2db)`.

Comment: well thats what i dont understand. i copy/paste the very same line, and i do a simple test and it connects just fine. like for example, i took that same line, did a select all from db where statement, and it came back as the data on the first row. which as you can see, is why im lost

Comment: I missed the 'i' in the answer, try it again now.